# Why does Bash output / is a directory?

Tags: bash

Sometimes when I make a typo in the terminal and accidentally tell Bash to interpret `/`, I get the output `bash: /: Is a directory`. Now I believe this output has to deal with the root directory or something of that sort.

But what I don't understand is that when I enter increasing amounts of forward-slashes it continues to output the same thing...

### Examples

//// --> `bash: ////: Is a directory`

//////// --> `bash: ////////: Is a directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>/</kbd> is the directory delimiter. Any string that ends in it is by definition a directory name:

```
example #This could be a file or directory
example/ #This is a directory in the current directory
/example/ #This is a directory in the root directory
```

Thus a series of <kbd>/</kbd>'s would be interpreted an a series of {null} directories.

Comment: But if the directory is null, why does Bash say it is a directory rather than saying does not exist?

Comment: most likely because the directory error comes before it attempts to find the command specified. IE the argument parser gives the directory error before bash attempts to find the command